# Normalization using a control (specific range of data in the column) using data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, bigdata, normalization

I am trying to normalize data using a reference or control for the various features included using the **data.table** Cran R package.

My table could look like this (with many many more rows and many more features/grouping columns):

```
myDF <- data.table(
        Grouping=rep(c("P1","P2"),each=6),
        type = rep(c(rep("samp",times=4),"CRTL","CRTL"),times=2),
        ID= rep(1:6, times=2),
        feat1 = rnorm(12),
        feat2 = rnorm(12)
    )
```

This generates the following data table (this is the output from this run):

> ```
>       Grouping  type  ID   feat1    feat2  
> 1:       P1     samp  1    0.9852  0.24133 
> 2:       P1     samp  2    0.2358  1.26750 
> 3:       P1     samp  3    1.2034  2.19410 
> 4:       P1     samp  4    0.5468 -0.42462 
> 5:       P1     CRTL  5    0.3997  0.95686 
> 6:       P1     CRTL  6    0.9915 -1.41417 
> 7:       P2     samp  1    0.6461 -1.19252 
> 8:       P2     samp  2    0.7926 -0.68735 
> 9:       P2     samp  3    0.9408  0.07738 
> 10:      P2     samp  4    0.2759  1.37948 
> 11:      P2     CRTL  5    1.0898 -0.07205 
> 12:      P2     CRTL  6    0.5325  1.21850
> ```

I would like to normalize so that for each `Grouping`, for each `type`, the median value of `feat1` and `feat2` (in my actual case, this would be a very long list of feature) are divided (**normalized**) by the median values for the type **'CRTL'**.

I was able to achieve this using the code below, but I hope there is a more elegant (and faster way) to do this.Here is the code I used:

```
cols_grouping=c('Grouping', 'type')
cols_features=c('feat1','feat2')

setkeyv(myDF,"Grouping")
myDF_norm=myDF[,lapply(.SD, median, rm.NA=TRUE), .SDcols=cols_features, by=cols_grouping]
setkeyv(myDF_norm,"Grouping")

crt_normalization = function(sub_table){
    for (col in cols_features) {
        i_col=paste0("i.",col)
        sub_table[[col]]=sub_table[[col]]/sub_table[[i_col]]
        sub_table[[i_col]]=NULL
    }
    return(sub_table)
}

myDF_norm=myDF_norm[
                 myDF_norm[type == "CRTL",
                      c("Grouping",cols_features),
                      with=FALSE]
                    ][,crt_normalization(.SD),by='Grouping']
```

This returns the properly normalized table:

> ```
>     Grouping   type  feat1    feat2         
>   1:    P1     samp  2.0629  -3.2994         
>   2:    P1     CRTL  1.0000   1.0000         
>   3:    P2     samp  0.2282  -0.5321         
>   4:    P2     CRTL  1.0000   1.0000
> ```

Hope that you have a methodology reli=ying on data.table that is perhaps a bit more elegant and performant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work

```
DT<-setDT(myDF) 
DT1<-DT[, lapply(.SD, median),.SDcols = (cols_features), by=cols_grouping]
DT1[DT1[type=="CRTL"],.(Grouping, type,med_feat1=
                          feat1/i.feat1, med_feat2=feat2/i.feat2),on="Grouping"]

   Grouping type med_feat1 med_feat2
1:       P1 samp 1.10121 -3.29936
2:       P1 CRTL 1.00000  1.00000
3:       P2 samp 0.88683 -0.53205
4:       P2 CRTL 1.00000  1.00000
```

Results are different from what you posted, however when I run your code, I get the same results

Updated option based on your requirement to work with a large number of variables. Still doesnt avoid the overhead of creating multiple 'i.' columns while doing a self join.

```
DT<-setDT(myDF) 
cols_grouping=c('Grouping', 'type')
N=2 # define the number of 'feat' variables
cols_features=paste0("feat",1:N) 
cols_features_i <-paste0("i.",cols_features)

DT1<-DT[, lapply(.SD, median),.SDcols = (cols_features), by=cols_grouping]
DT2<-DT1[DT1[type=="CRTL"],,on="Grouping"]
DT2[,paste0("med_",cols_features):=Map(`/`, mget(cols_features), mget(cols_features_i))]
DT2[,grep("^i", colnames(DT2)):=NULL] # drop the unnecessary variables.
> DT2

   Grouping type    feat1     feat2 med_feat1 med_feat2
1:       P1 samp  0.19585  0.562563   0.31809  -0.38011
2:       P1 CRTL  0.61570 -1.479994   1.00000   1.00000
3:       P2 samp  0.19385  0.087063  -2.66163  -0.99856
4:       P2 CRTL -0.07283 -0.087189   1.00000   1.00000
```

A more elegant answer must be out there...

Comment: Different results are most probably to different random values in the initial creation of the `data.table`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Yes, the table is indeed using a random variable. Perhaps not the best choice on my end. Sorry.

The only issue with your solution is that I have 1000 feat columns (which name is not constant). I cannot foreseeably type this for every feature.

Also, this would leave behind the i.feat cols, so the data.table will be bigger than needed.

Comment: Updated to deal with several feat columns. The code also takes care of removing the i.feat columns as well.

Comment: Using the Map function is pretty good! I'll flag this as the solution

Answer (score 0):

To compare the results, better define a seed. I pretty much just use some basic merge features. Don't know if this version is faster than yours.

```
set.seed(123)
myDF <- data.table(
        Grouping=rep(c("P1","P2"),each=6),
        type = rep(c(rep("samp",times=4),"CRTL","CRTL"),times=2),
        ID= rep(1:6, times=2),
        feat1 = rnorm(12),
        feat2 = rnorm(12)
)   
merge( x = myDF[, .(Median.feat1 = median(feat1)
                    , Median.feat2 = median(feat2)), by = list(Grouping, type)]
           , y = myDF[like(type, "CRTL" ), .(Median.feat1 = median(feat1)
                        , Median.feat2 = median(feat2)), by = list(Grouping, type)]
           , by.x = c("Grouping")
           , by.y  = c("Grouping")
    )[, .(Grouping
          ,type = type.x
          , Median.feat1 = Median.feat1.x/Median.feat1.y
          , Median.feat2 = Median.feat2.x/Median.feat2.y
          )]
```

The `merge` results in the following table:

```
   Grouping type.x Median.feat1.x Median.feat2.x type.y Median.feat1.y Median.feat2.y
1:       P1   samp      0.1510875      0.1236681   CRTL      0.7733013      0.4074872
2:       P1   CRTL      0.7733013      0.4074872   CRTL      0.7733013      0.4074872
3:       P2   samp      0.2108585     -0.1386234   CRTL     -0.3634114     -1.1849065
4:       P2   CRTL     -0.3634114     -1.1849065   CRTL     -0.3634114     -1.1849065
```

and the final results look like the following:

```
   Grouping type Median.feat1 Median.feat2
1:       P1 samp    0.1953798    0.3034897
2:       P1 CRTL    1.0000000    1.0000000
3:       P2 samp   -0.5802199    0.1169910
4:       P2 CRTL    1.0000000    1.0000000
```